# How to use an anemometer to measure inline duct fan performance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I've recently been shopping around for inline duct exhaust fans.

It seems there are many models out there claiming the same CFM rating, but actual performance varies quite a bit.

The scientist in me decided it makes sense to buy an inexpensive ($15-20) anemometer from AliExpress so that I can test a handful of models and get some empirical data.

This brings me to my question:
-the anemometer has what appears to be a 1-1.5" opening
-I have 4", 6" and 8" inline duct fans
-I plan on designing and printing reducers to adapt the output or input of the exhaust fans to the anemometer
-I see there's a formula CFM = FPM x Duct Cross Sectional Area

Will this work?

I would measure air speed through the anemometer, and convert that to CFM?
Drag/friction through the adapter would probably not be accounted for, but would I otherwise be getting at least ballpark close numbers?